# Is it possible use Tumplr API to POST to non-default user blog?

Tags: api, tumblr

I reviewed the API here http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#api_write

I did not see any way to post to non-default blog?
I mean, if a user has more than one blog on Tumblr, is it possible to select which blog to send a post to using the write api?
I am using OAuth based calls to API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a user's account information, you need to send a POST request to call http://www.tumblr.com/api/authenticate first. If you have already authenticated using OAuth, you don't need to send email and password as parameters, but you still need to call this method to get a list of blogs the user has.

When you send a POST request to call http://www.tumblr.com/api/write, you need to send an additional parameter called 'group' to post to a non-default log. The value of group parameter should be:

- 'blogname.tumblr.com' if it's a public blog
- private-id if it's a private blog

Comment: Thank you. I have already figured it out and wrote a Tumblr plugin for Lampcms to post to Tumblr blogs. If anyone is interested it on github https://github.com/snytkine/LampCMS/tree/master/lib/Lampcms/Modules/Tumblr the demo is http://support.lampcms.com